# C# Highlight PropertyItem in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, validation, propertygrid

I'm trying to "highlight" a property item in a WinForms PropertyGrid when the validation process of the user input  returns false. I would like for example, change the font or color background of the property when the user inserts an incorrect value. The property I need to change is a `ExpandableObject`.

Comment: The winforms property grid doesn't support that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find a workaround.